# What does a filled, solid circle mean in a chemical structure?

Tags: molecular-structure

I'm looking in a textbook at an asphaltene molecule.
[image]

The two aromatic rings next to the Nitrogen are shaded. What does that mean? I think the Nitrogen's create delocalized electrons in this configuration, so maybe the shaded circle is the range over which that free radical is delocalized?

Comment: This is not a universally accepted notation.

Comment: So it means "Ooh, I made a pretty picture!"

Comment: The open circles of course represent aromatic rings, however this is no now the accepted drawing. The accepted way is to draw out the double bonds. //  I'd guess that the solid circles are for heterocyclic aromatic rings.

Comment: Dunno, there is a hetrocylic ring with sulfur that doesnt get the solid circle. I've tried contacting the authors but this was long time ago: Gafanova O.V.,Yarranton W. (2001) The Stabilization of Water-in-Hydrocarbon Emulsions by Asphaltenes and Resins, J. Colloid Interf. Sci. 241, 469-478. .... IGNORE! I've found Professor Yarranton.

Comment: @Tunneller The sulfur ring isn't unsaturated so doesn't really count as an exception.

Comment: BTW, this may be called multisubstituted bathroom tile ;-)